# Separating Two Classes from Simulated Data

Tags: r, machine-learning, simulate

Was wondering if someone may help me with understanding `abline()` in `r`. My code is as follows:

```
N = 500
fx1 <- runif(N,-2,2)
fx2 <- runif(N,-2,2)
X <- cbind(fx1,fx2)

a <- runif(1,-1,1) 
b <- runif(1,-1,1)
  
plot(X, xlim=c(-2,2),ylim=c(-2,2), xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
abline(a,b)
```

Here is an image of the generated data:

[image]

What I am trying to do, is create two classes using this data after the `abline` line is calculate, although I am unsure how to go about this. Was wondering if someone may help.

Comment: Have you read the help page, `?abline`?  It describes how `a` and `b` are interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

with these two instructions

```
a <- runif(1,-1,1) 
b <- runif(1,-1,1)
```

you are generating the parameters of a line. Specifically, intercept and slope

`abline(a,b)` construct a line based on your intercept a, and slope b

details [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/graphics/versions/3.6.2/topics/abline)

Comment: Thanks, go ahead and give my answer a look. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I got it, I have read the documentation and I have a better understanding.

Basically, I needed to modify my existing code in order to make more sense with variable naming to the following:

```
N = 1000
x <- runif(N,-2,2)
y <- runif(N,-2,2)
a <- runif(1,-1,1) 
b <- runif(1,-1,1)
```

which gives me the following graph when using ggplot

```
ggplot(X, aes(x= x, y = y)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(slope = b, intercept = a)
```

[image]

Then, I just make a `ifelse` and plug in the numbers to see if it is greater than `y`

```
class <- as.matrix(ifelse(
 y > a + x * b, '0', '1' 
))
```

combine into a dataframe and replot:

```
X <- cbind.data.frame(x, y, class)
ggplot(X, aes(x= x, y = y, color = class)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_abline(slope = b, intercept = a)
```

[image]